# How to UPDATE only the "most recent" record while joining several tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This question has been asked a few different ways on this site, but I can't seem to figure how to implement an update in this specific case. Generally, I am trying to update the most recent `ContactNote` for every `Contact` that belongs to a `TeamId` and has specific `Categories`. It's a fairly straight forward DB setup (see diagram below).

I have successfully created a "select clause" that returns all the records I would like to update, but when I add the `UPDATE` language, MySQL gives me the error: `Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'cn1' for update in FROM clause`

Any guidance is appreciated.

Working SELECT Clause

```
SELECT cn1.* from ContactNote cn1
    INNER JOIN Contact contact on contact.ContactId = cn1.ContactId
    INNER JOIN ContactCategory contactCategory on contactCategory.ContactId = contact.ContactId
    INNER JOIN Category category on category.CategoryId = contactCategory.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN ContactNote contactNote
        ON contactNote.ContactNoteId =
        (SELECT cn2.ContactNoteId
            FROM ContactNote cn2
            WHERE contact.ContactId = cn2.ContactId
            ORDER BY cn2.NoteDateTime DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
where contact.TeamId = 1
    and contact.SpouseLastName = 'Rhodes'
    and category.`Name` in ('Sphere')
;
```

Non-Working UPDATE Clause

```
update ContactNote cn1
    INNER JOIN Contact contact on contact.ContactId = cn1.ContactId
    INNER JOIN ContactCategory contactCategory on contactCategory.ContactId = contact.ContactId
    INNER JOIN Category category on category.CategoryId = contactCategory.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN ContactNote contactNote
        ON contactNote.ContactNoteId =
        (SELECT cn2.ContactNoteId
            FROM ContactNote cn2
            WHERE contact.ContactId = cn2.ContactId
            ORDER BY cn2.NoteDateTime DESC
            LIMIT 1
        )
SET cn1.IsProspecting = b'1' 
where contact.TeamId = 1
    and contact.SpouseLastName = 'Rhodes'
    and category.`Name` in ('Sphere')
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL generally doesn't like it when you SELECT from the table in a subquery and try to UPDATE it in the same statement.

A workaround is to join to the table instead of selecting in a subquery. We're looking for cases where there is no matching row with a greater date:

```
update ContactNote cn
    INNER JOIN Contact contact on contact.ContactId = cn.ContactId
    INNER JOIN ContactCategory contactCategory on contactCategory.ContactId = contact.ContactId
    INNER JOIN Category category on category.CategoryId = contactCategory.CategoryId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactNote gt
        ON gt.ContactId = cn.ContactId AND gt.NodeDateTime > cn.NodeDateTime
SET cn.IsProspecting = b'1' 
WHERE contact.TeamId = 1
    AND contact.SpouseLastName = 'Rhodes'
    AND category.`Name` IN ('Sphere')
    AND gt.ContactId IS NULL -- meaning there is no note with a greater datetime
;
```

LEFT OUTER JOIN returns NULL for all columns of the joined table, if there is no matching row found. If the condition is trying to find notes with a greater NodeDateTime, and none is found, then the NodeDateTime in the row `cn` must be the one with the greatest (most recent) datetime for the respective conctact.

This does have one weakness: what if there are multiple notes tied for most recent? It would update all those for which there is no note with a greater datetime, which might update multiple notes. Is this what you want?